# Golang mgo MongoDB bson.ObjectId non utf-8 error

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, go, mgo

I'm developing in go on my Mac using mongo and mgo driver.

Everything works great on my Mac. When my friend works on the same codebase from his windows machine, we get these weird non utf-8 bson.ObjectIds.

Here is a screenshot from mongolab.com (a hosted mongo server)

[image]

My code simply uses:

```
thing.Id = bson.NewObjectId() 
thing.eventId = event.Id
```

Has anyone had this issue? Does anyone know how to deal with that

Edit: All bson functions used in this codebase are:

```
thing.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
thing.Id = bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
idString = thing.Id.Hex()
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you writing the `thing.eventId` field to the database? The `eventId` field is ignored by the BSON encoder because the field is not exported.

Comment: did you get this problem sorted? I think I'm having the same issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244438/mgo-newobjectid-corrupt-on-insert

Comment: It was an outdated version of mgo on my buddies windows system.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode replacement character in the screenshot suggests that the application is treating object ids as UTF-8 encoded text. Object ids contain binary data, not UTF-8 encoded text.

Use the [Hex](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method to convert an object id to human readable text.

Use [ObjectIdHex](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectIdHex) to convert the hex string representation back to an object id. Be careful to protect the call to ObjectIdHex with [IsObjectIdHex](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#IsObjectIdHex).

Comment: Maybe utf-8 isn't my issue. When I use my mac, the above snapshot would show all human readable characters. When the objects are created/used on the windows machine we get these weird characters. And this is on mongolab website.

Comment: It's pretty obvious from [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) that they are using Go strings as just a collection of bytes and so I'd expect "interesting" output if trying to print it as-is (e.g. without %x or %q formatting). That's perfectly [legal in Go](http://blog.golang.org/strings) (even though normally you'd see `[]byte` used for this, the advantage of using `string` is that it's read-only).

Comment: If I was them and I wanted to use an underlying string type I'd have made a custom `type ObjectIDType string` (but with a better name) to make it clearer that it's not a plain string.

Comment: @ThunderCat d'oh, I read over that too quickly, ignore my second comment :^)