# mgo NewObjectId corrupt on insert

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

If I generate a new object id for a document in mgo:

```
obId := bson.NewObjectId()
```

and then insert it, it ends up in mongo (looking via the cli) as

```
"_id" : "U�`�\u0006@�\rU\u0000\u0000\u0001"
```

When it should be

```
"_id" : ObjectId("559a47643d9827f0d9405420")
```

Same goes if I try and update an existing document where I generate the id by

```
obId := bson.ObjectIdHex(stringId)
```

It still gets serialized to the corrupted format.

My struct which I'm trying to insert looks like this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Id            bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you print it where it appears as `"_id" : "U�`�\u0006@�\rU\u0000\u0000\u0001"`?

Comment: I'm using the `mongo` cli command and just copying the output of `db.mycol.find()`. Thing is, ids that were autogenerated appear as `ObjectId("blah...")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representation `` "U�`�\u0006@�\rU\u0000\u0000\u0001" `` is clearly indicating that an ObjectId got sent to the database as a string rather than as a properly typed object id. Every such case before was a code path in the application side delivering the string explicitly as such by mistake. I recommend investigating every code path that inserts objects in that collection, and if you can find no case that is sending it as an actual string, then try to create a reproducer and report it upstream to the mgo driver.

**Update:** Per your comment below, the issue is being caused because some part of the application is using an `ObjectId` type from a package that is not the one actually used during communication with the database. This has the effect described above: the `ObjectId` type coming from the wrong package is just a normal string, as far as the correct `bson` package is concerned.

Comment: The issue is hopefully solved. I am using a library which imports mgo via `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`. I was importing mgo myself as well as `gopkg.in/v2/mgo`. After copying the external code into the project and making them all import from `labix.org/v2/mgo` it now works. So the path confusion possibly caused it.

Comment: labix.org/v2/mgo is extremely old. Please use gopkg.in/mgo.v2 instead.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo, will update the imports to that path.